# Differences between global and pointer access

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

Wondering what the differences between the following two bits (labeled Method 1, and Method 2) are, any benefits / risks associated with either, and finally, is there a better way.

```
 typedef struct
 {
   int iAnInteger;
 } s_Thing;

 s_Thing sMine;

 void SomeFunction(int myInt)
 {
    /* Method 1 */
    s_Thing *pMine = &sMine;

    pMine->iAnInteger = 0;

    /* Method 2 */
    sMine.iAnInteger = 0;
 }
```

As stated, what are the advantages / disadvantages, best practices?

Thanks!

Comment: **Nitpick:** Is it necessary to have `AnInteger` in your variable name? The type already encodes that knowledge making it a little redundant. And if the type changes, will you remember to change the name to prevent misleading others?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are getting at with this question; there is still a global object in both cases.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, realizing that there is a global in both cases.  Is there an agreed best practice for something like this (a global struct).

Comment: byxor, the variable names are simply my lack of creativity at the moment, the question essentially focuses on pointers vs globals

Comment: The agreed best practice is not to use a global struct at all. If you use one, your program design is bad and discussing further "best practices" from there is pointless, since there are no recommendations for how to write bad code in the "best" way.

Comment: But the question doesn't seem to be about "pointers vs. globals", but about pointers to globals vs. globals. Best practice is probably to not do anything like this from the start.

Comment: @1point8zero61 still doesn't make much sense, if you have a global anyway (as I tried to explain in my answer). The only way your design would *benefit* from using a pointer is by making the function unaware of the global (IOW, passing the pointer as suggested by Bathsheba).

Comment: Thanks Lundin.  Recommendations to avoid?

Comment: One always should write the *simplest code possible*. Thus don't use a pointer if you don't need it.

Comment: They are different ways of doing the same bad thing.  

Accessing a  global through a local pointer provides no protection from the evils of globals, and has no advantages.  For advice on globals and how to avoid them read Jack Ganssle's [A Pox on Globals](https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals).

Comment: Why down voting? This is a valid question about C. Yes, this is a bad practice. However, C allows this, so people may just wonder how and why those methods are different. Their interest may or may not be just academic, but it does not make the question any worse.

Answer (score 5):

Method 3:

```
void SomeFunction(int myInt, s_Thing* pWho)
{
    pWho->iAnInteger = 0;
}
```

is even better since will be more maintainable if you make changes to how instances of `s_Thing` are created.

Your other two methods both suffer from localisation issues: try to limit the number of functions that modify data held at global scope.

Comment: what do you mean by "localisation" here? (I still don't get that word here although I fully agree with your stylistic tips)

Comment: Thanks, this approach seems quite logical

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 and Method 2 basically do the same thing, Method 1 just adds an extra level of indirection for no real reason or benefit.

Both methods modify the contents of a global object, leading to *tight [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))*, *[re-entrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing))* and *[thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)* issues.

The *right* thing to do is for `SomeFunction` to take an `s_Thing` as a writable parameter:

```
void SomeFunction( int myInt, s_Thing *myThing )
{
  ...
  myThing->iAnInteger = 0;
  ...
}
```

which would get called something like

```
int main( void )
{
  s_Thing sMine;
  ...
  SomeFunction( anInt, &sMine );
  ...
}
```

As a rule, functions *should* communicate via parameters and return values, rather than by setting globals.  There *are* times when using a global is
necessary (such as with [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)), but life will be easier if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks.  In the absence of a main (i.e. RTOS), where would be the past place to define sMine?

Comment: @1point8zero61: that depends entirely on what your application does.  How long does the instance of `sMine` need to live?

Comment: sMine lives throughout the entire program. It contains all related hardware details. It is accessed by many tasks. I like the idea you suggest about defining in main(), but obviously, this is not an option.

Comment: @1point8zero61 Declare it in the module it belongs to. On embedded systems, it is perfectly fine to declare variables at file scope, as long as they are declared `static`. This blocks them from being accessed from all over the place - only the file where they reside can access them. Still, care about re-entrancy must be taken.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks.  Does this mean that a 'global' at file level is actually acceptable practice?  This is essentially what I have.  A file called time.c with get / set functions accessed from a SW clock in a different module.  When the 'set' is run, it increments as shown in my original snippet.

Comment: @1point8zero61 Global means accessible throughout the whole project. A `static` file scope variable is only accessible from the specific .c file. If that `static` variable is only accessible through setters/getters to the outside world, then that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, except readability.

Consider this: if you got struct, which has struct as one of its members, which in turn has a struct as one of its members, which in turn... Well, you got the point.

Then if you need to compare value `A` with value `B` of the very inner struct, you'll end up with a line like

```
Struct1.Struct2.Struct3.Struct4.Struct5.A == Struct1.Struct2.Struct3.Struct4.Struct5.B
```

Alternatively, you could put

```
MY_STRUCT* pMeaningfulName = &Struct1.Struct2.Struct3.Struct4.Struct5;
pMeaningfulName.A == pMeaningfulName.B;
```

which is much more readable and shorter, especially if you have to do many repetitive operations with the same struct.

As far as the rest goes, most compilers nowadays should produce the same code for both methods.